# C# to VB conversion issues

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

Hi I am trying to convert some code from C# to VB but I have a couple of problems because of my lack of knowledge of C# (or perhaps VB). I am hoping somebody with more skill can put me right.

I am using the conversion tool here:
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/
to convert some code found here:
http://www.urmanet.ch/?p=11

The code is designed to make a deep copy of EF entities.

After correcting the && on line 87, the conversion completes OK. A few imports later and some simple errors fixed, the remaining errors I could not solve are as follows:

1: The line

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Shared Function Clone(entityObject As EntityObject) As EntityObject
```

is flagged saying that extension methods can only be defined in modules. It is defined within a class but I presume this worked in C# so why would I get this error in VB?

2: There are quite a number of lines like this:

```
For Each [property] As var In properties
```

where the 'as var' section is flagged as being not defined; I'm not entirely sure what 'as var' means, can I just remove this and allow the compiler to infer the type?

3: There is an error in this line of code:

```
Dim t = GetType(EntityCollection(Of )).MakeGenericType(New () {[property].PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()(0)})
```

there is a squiggle under the '(' after 'New' which says Type Expected, I have no idea what to make of this line, and hence how to fix it, is somebody able to clarify it a bit?

4: The line

```
Private Shared ReadOnly _tracking As New List()
```

informs me that there are too few type arguments to System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T). Is this because of some difference between C# and VB?

Thanks very much for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions like this are *far* easier to answer if you post the original C# code, rather than just your failed attempts at conversion. As it is now, we can only *guess* at what the code is supposed to do, rather than doing the conversion ourselves.

But I'll take a stab at guessing anyway...

1. Presumably, the code in question was actually declared in a `static` class in C#. Those are called "modules" in VB.NET for compatibility reasons. They work exactly the same way; trust the compiler's suggestion and move your extensions methods into modules.
2. Declaring a variable `as var` is how you do [anonymous typing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) in C#. The equivalent in VB.NET is turning on `Option Infer` in your project's Properties. You will need to remove the `as var` declaration, and then the compiler will automatically infer the variable's type, just as in C#.
3. I have no idea what this line of code is intended to do, as you haven't shown the original *working* code in C#, but you need to remove `New` and change the way that you declare the array:

   ```
   Dim t = GetType(EntityCollection(Of )).MakeGenericType([property].PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()(0))
   ```
4. No, this is not caused from a difference between VB.NET and C#. It's because you've used the generic `List(Of T)` class, but failed to specify the type you want to use. For example, your code should look like the following:

   ```
   Private Shared ReadOnly _tracking As New List(Of Integer)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I gave the full link to the C# source in my original post, here it is again:  http://www.urmanet.ch/?p=11  and its the main block of code thats 180 lines long. I have to go out but will look over your suggestions as soon as I return.

Comment: Thanks very much for these answers, that helped me get the code fully compiled. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

1. go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) to see how extension methods work in VB. It may be tedious to manually convert these if there are a lot of them. maybe you should consider leaving them in C#, as the code compiles to the same intermediate language.
2. `var` means the compiler infers the type.
3. in C# you can say `new[] { 1, 2, 3 } and the compiler will infer the type of the array for you based on the elements, but I don't know if this works in VB.
4. you must put the type in the parentheses to create the correct generic type. Something like `New List(string)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will give feedback when I get back.

Comment: Again thanks for your comments, the code compiles properly now.

Answer (score 1):

For #3, the `MakeGenericType` method expects a variadic array of `Type`. You can accomplish this with `Dim t = GetType(EntityCollection(Of )).MakeGenericType([property].PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()(0))`

For #4, I can't imagine how that could compile in C# either. However, looking at the full source it appears as though `Private Shared ReadOnly _tracking As New List(Of SelfReferencesTracking)` is the correct thing.

Comment: @TripleAntigen: I found the original (and I think I got your answer -- see my edit), but you should post the exact line with a problem. You can't expect us to sift through hundreds of lines of code without giving us some hints.

Comment: Great, both suggestions helped a lot. Thanks again.